# exports is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am trying out aws chatbot function following this example over here. [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs2-prepare.html) I have followed the steps on the webpage but I am unsure as to why I keep getting this error

```
Test Event Name
Pizza

Response
{
  "errorType": "ReferenceError",
  "errorMessage": "exports is not defined in ES module scope",
  "trace": [
    "ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope",
    "    at file:///var/task/index.mjs:34:1",
    "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)",
    "    at async Promise.all (index 0)",
    "    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)",
    "    at async _tryAwaitImport (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:921:16)",
    "    at async _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:970:86)",
    "    at async _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:994:16)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1035:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1206:1"
  ]
}
```